# Invoking the method. How to set parameters?

Tags: java, class, reflection

I have a program where I have to choose a method from the list and invoke its methods using reflection's `invoke()`.

I have a problem with setting parameters for each method.
As you can see in the code:

```
Class c = String.class;
Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[] { String.class };
Method concatMethod;
Object[] arguments = new Object[] { secondWord };
try {
concatMethod = c.getMethod(metto, parameterTypes);
result = (String) concatMethod.invoke(firstWord, arguments);
} //some catches (…)
```

For example for simple_method (let it be “toString”) has no parameters. But for example for “concat” - there is 1 additional String.

The get *metto* from lista which is getting methods from here:

```
Method mets[] = null;
for (Method m : mets) {
                if (m.getDeclaringClass() == actionClass) {
                    String parame = "";
                    Class[] paramTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
                    for (Class c : paramTypes) {
                        if(!parame.equals("")) parame += " , " + c.getName();
                        else parame = c.getName();
                    }

                    String name = m.getName();
                    lista.add(method);
                }
            }
```

My question is how to set parameterTypes to get String or to get nothing next time?

Comment: Is the last `method` meant to be `m`? And I don't understand your question. Or what your code is trying to do. It seems to do a lot of pointless stuff - creates a string and then throws it away, gets another string then throws it away...

Comment: If you are calling methods of known types (`String`) why use reflection?

Comment: @RobinGreen I edited my question. I think that my question is more clear.

Comment: @zapl class String is only an example. I don't know from which class I will have to get methods.

Comment: IS THE LAST `METHOD` SUPPOSED TO BE `M`?

Comment: And your actual question - the last line - is still unclear. What do you mean by "next time"? For that matter, what do you mean by "nothing"?

Comment: @RobinGreen because in one time I will invoke the method 'toString', and in another time I will invoke the method 'concat'. By nothing i mean null (in 'toString' you don't need to have parameters, but in 'concat' you need parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *set* the parameter types - they already exist and cannot be changed by reflection - you *get* them. Do you understand the difference between a setter method and a getter method?

Comment: So how do should I do to get the parameters?

Comment: You are already doing so. It seems that you don't have a clue what you are doing. Maybe you should.. I don't know... read the Javadocs? Did it ever occur to you to do that?